# HTML <meta> redirections for files?

Tags: html, redirect

I was reading [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Redirections#html_redirections) and read this in HTML directions section:

> Obviously, this method only works with HTML, and cannot be used for images or other types of content.

What does this mean? Can't I do something like this?

```html
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; URL=https://example.com/image.jpg" />
</head>
```

Comment: Of course you can.  All it's saying is that you can only include the `<meta>` tag in HTML files.  If you have a JPG or an MP3, there's obviously no place for you to put the `<meta>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

The text you quote is referring to where you can redirect **from** not where you can redirect **to**.

You can’t write a `<meta>` tag inside a JPEG, for example, and have the browser load the image and then load a different URL because of it.